# Postsを持たないUsersだけを削除するSQL文の書き方を教えてください

Tags: sql, postgresql

postgresqlについて質問です。

- users

  - id
  - name
- posts

  - id
  - user_id
  - name

`users ---< posts`

このような関係のテーブルがあります。
`posts`をもたない`users`のデータをdeleteしたいのですが、sql文の書き方がわかりません。

教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんなSQLでいけると思います。

```
delete from users
where not exists(
  select * from posts where posts.user_id = users.id
)
```